# ASP.NET Identity 2 Separation of Email and UserName and using Email to login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

By default, ASP.NET Identity has the UserName and Email fields as being the email the user inputs. I've already changed it so that my system takes in a separate username and email for the user.

My problem is that now I cannot login to the system because of the checks Identity does against both the UserName and Email.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep these two fields separate and unique, while being able to just check against the Email field in order to login to the system?

I noticed that `public virtual Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout);` checks the userName, but changing this to the email does nothing and I am still unable to login.

I've also looked at these other questions:

[ASP.Net UserName to Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481835/asp-net-username-to-email)

[Allowing both email and username for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611957/allowing-both-email-and-username-for-authentication)

for possible solutions and found nothing really allowed me to do what I want.

Is there anything else I could possibly attempt in order to have separate usernames and emails, while still being able to login with the email field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, it looks like you can only authenticate using a username, but there's no reason why you can't find the user name from an email address:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
if (user == null)
{

    return //some error or throw
}
var result = await 
    SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, 
                                      model.Password, 
                                      model.RememberMe, 
                                      shouldLockout: false);
```

Comment: thnks, exactly what i was looking for +1 from me too